# Zip/Unzip with php

Tags: php, yii

I am doing a backup module, I need to zip all the webapp folder, I use this method:

```
function agregar_zip($dir, $zip){

            if (is_dir($dir)) {

                if ($da = opendir($dir)) {          

                    while (($archivo = readdir($da))!== false) {  

                        if (is_dir($dir . $archivo) && $archivo!="." && $archivo!=".."){

                        agregar_zip($dir.$archivo . "/", $zip);  


                        }elseif(is_file($dir.$archivo) && $archivo!="." && $archivo!=".."){

                        $zip->addFile($dir.$archivo, $dir.$archivo);                    
                        }            
                    }

                    closedir($da);
                }
            }      
        }   
        $zip = new ZipArchive();

        $dir = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../';
        $rutaFinal="c:/xampp/htdocs/";

        $archivoZip = "backup.zip";  

        if($zip->open($archivoZip,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===true) {  
            agregar_zip($dir, $zip);
            $zip->close();

            @rename($archivoZip, "c:/xampp/htdocs/backup.zip");

            if (file_exists($rutaFinal.$archivoZip)){

            }else{

              Yii::app()->params['errores'] = Yii::app()->params['errores']."</br>No se ha creado el ZIP con éxito.";
            }                    
        }
```

When I open the file.zip, I have this structure:

C:/->xampp->htdocs->mywebapp(Here is all I need)

But If I do "extract here" Its unzip the right content, but If I do with php it create a folder in destination called xampp, inside it htdocs, inside it mywebapp(With the right content).

I need to zip only the app folder not all the route. This way when I unzip with php only unzip app folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the "/../" from this line

```
$dir = Yii::app()->basePath.'/../';
```

should be

```
$dir = Yii::app()->basePath;
```

Comment: It doesn't take the route properly that way and doesn't create de file.zip

Answer (score 0):

There is better way to make zip with yii.
Yii has a zip [extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ezip/).

**Usage example from the docs above:**

Introduce EZip to Yii. Add definition to CWebApplication config file (main.php)

```
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'zip'=>array(
        'class'=>'application.extensions.zip.EZip',
    ),
    ...
),
```

Now you can access EZip methods as follows:

```
$zip = Yii::app()->zip;

$zip->makeZip('./','./toto.zip'); // make an ZIP archive
var_export($zip->infosZip('./toto.zip'), false); // get infos of this ZIP archive (without files content)
var_export($zip->infosZip('./toto.zip')); // get infos of this ZIP archive (with files content)
$zip->extractZip('./toto.zip', './1/'); //
```